# Debugging a site for IE9 (jquery isotope)

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-9, jquery-isotope

I'm asking if someone could help me debug a site for IE9. The site uses jquery isotope to filter some list elements. Although it uses combination filters, it's nothing too complicated and it works in all browsers I tested, even IE. But it does not work in my clients' browser, which is IE9 and under the advanced internet options "deactivate script debugging" is checked, so the IE debugger doesn't run on default. 
Ok, now my concrete questions:

- Is there really some script error I didn't find yet or is it some special IE9 bug which is why script debugging should always be active?
- There are no errors that have anything to do with isotope, but there still seems to be a problem with @font-face – could this cause the whole site to stop working?

Here's the link: http://www.goethe.de/ins/gr/lp/prj/lef/lre/deindex.htm

Problem: Using the filter dropdowns doesn't work in IE9 when built-in script debugging is not active. Also the developer console has to be closed, because when opening the console, script debugging get's activated. That's why for me it's impossible to reproduce the error, because I have IE11 installed and the only way to emulate IE9 is using the console. But I tested and got the error on several PCs from my client.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

-- Alani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blowing up on calls to `console.log` *which IE does not support unless dev tools are open!*.

As a quick hack/fix add this to your JS:

```
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {log: function() {}};
}
```

This should put a dummy `console.log` method in place to avoid the crash. Alternatively just don't call it!